Are interface/boundary conditions for EM fields only generally valid in the static case?
Griffiths derives these conditions in the respective electrostatics and magnetostatics chapters, though does not comment too much on them. For example, he uses
$$\oint_C \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}=0 $$
to show that $E^\parallel_2 = E^\parallel_1$. But this is only true if $\ \partial_t\mathbf{B}=0$, which isn't always true. Most sources don't seem to comment on this. Do they, then, apply in all cases, or just in the static case?

You already saw that those conditions are in electrostatics and magnetostatics. After you actually get the full electrodynamics (which you can easily see, as anything that comes after the full set of Maxwell's equations), you should be redoing the same arguments to obtain the corrected version. Then you can connect to mike stone's answer.

@naturallyInconsistent In the electrodynamics chapter Griffiths argues the boundary conditions are the same because, for example, a surface integral of an infinitesimal loop will have no flux. I can buy this argument but I don't think it's too rigorous.

Again, mike stone's answer gave you some insights into that. Of course it aint rigorous; Griffiths is one of the first standard textbooks that simplified the treatment of the subject. If you wanted rigour and comprehensiveness, you would have gone for the much more difficult standard graduate textbook.

But is the claim that the boundary conditions (at least in many cases) remain the same correct, then, despite the argument for it not being rigorous? I would think so. In other subjects, like optics, I've seen these boundary conditions applied to EM waves even though they're clearly not static.

Sigh. This would be the 3rd time I'm referencing mike stone's answer that you have already accepted. Those arguments are clearly not rigorous for the reason that he had already explicitly stated for you! There must be corrections, but yes, those corrections tend to be small, and so as a short-hand, many treatments would simply ignore them, e.g. those optics treatments that you have read. You can, and should, estimate the magnitude of the correction term assuming the boundary conditions are correct, and thus check if the assumptions are good or not.

You need a $\int B dA$ to get a correction.  For a perfect conductor the integral is over an infinitesimal area between the inside and outside of the material, so  if the $B$ field is finite,  it  gives zero.
For finite conductivity there are frequency-dependent skin depth corrections.
